# Escaping output in a Zend View Helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've got a view helper in Zend Framework that handles repetitive display tasks, in this instance returning a rating for a business.  How do I escape the output of the rating comment, for instance, within a view helper? I'm looking for the equivalent `$this->escape()` method used in a view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for another method: if your helper extends `Zend_View_Helper_Abstract` (and it probably does), you can just use its `$view` property...

```
$this->view->escape(...)
```

Otherwise you may implement your own `setView` method (as described [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.custom)), which will be called when the helper is instantiated. It usually operates on the same-named property.

Comment: Ugh, how did I miss that? Accepted answer coming your way. Thanks.